# Reducing the number of reads firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dating kind of app (without chat support) in which I am showing list of all the profiles that matches certain criteria to user. I have used realtime snapshot listener for this.

```
 query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshot,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (snapshot != null && !snapshot.isEmpty()) {
                    List<FeedDetails> feedDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : snapshot.getDocuments()) {
                        FeedDetails feedDetails = document.toObject(FeedDetails.class);
                        feedDetailsList.add(feedDetails);
                    }
                    feedItemAdapter.updateData(feedDetailsList);
                } 

            }
        });
```

In individual profile doc, I have 10-12 field with one online/offline info field. So lets say if no other field changed but online/offline status changed for some profiles then listener is going to read that document again. Is there any way to cut down those reads?

Comment: Do you want to cut down the read of a single property?

Comment: Yes, I don't want that for each time some one goes offline or online, user feed refreshes because that would cause 10-12 more reads/profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a 10-12 field with one online/offline info field. So let's say if no other field changed but online/offline status changed for some profiles then the listener is going to read that document again.

There is no way in Cloud Firestore in which you can listen only to a set of properties of a document and exclude others. It's the entire document or nothing. So if this field `online=true` is changed into `online=false`, then you will get the entire document.

Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level and always return complete documents. Unfortunately, there is no way to request only a part of the document with the client-side SDK, although this option does exist in the server-side SDK's [select()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/Query.html#select-java.lang.String...-) method.

If you don't want to get notified for specific fields, consider adding an extra collection with documents that will contain only those fields. So create that additional collection where each document just contains the data you don't need. In this way, you won't be notified for online/offline changes.

Comment: You can also take a look at one of my articles regarding on **[How to reduce the number of read operations in Cloud Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-read-operations-in-cloud-firestore-9f9d6f5a271)**.

Comment: There is one parameter lastseen along with this online/offline and I am ordering my query on the basis of that. So I guess to make separate collection is not possible for this, otherwise making collection would have been good idea.

Comment: If you need to query after that property then it should be present in the document. However, you can query the additional collection that contains the elements with the property you don't want to be synchronized and then perform another query to actually get the data, from the first collection. It will do the trick but it will a little expensive.

Comment: I have removed the online/offline field from document and made subcollection doc that will have online and lastseen filed. In this I am safe that I won't get notified for these changes, but doing this would also mean that now I have to read these two each time user opens feed as they will not be cached. It's like choosing between reading them each time vs reading full doc when these changes. Since other user might go online/offline multiple times so putting it in collection makes more sense for now. What's your say?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a trade between the denormalization and the number of reads. I cannot advise you because I don't know your budgets, so it's up to you to decide which is better.

Comment: I was thinking about not storing last seen data in firestore. I will populate all other details from firestore and last seen data from realtime database. Because anyways I am reading that data separately from subcolletcion. Is it right thing to do? or Should I use subcollection thing only?

Comment: Why not? If it solved your problem, you can go ahead with it. Both database solutions are working very well together.